# Selenium Ide - Select Options

Tags: selenium, ide

I'm stuck here:

https://www.otelo.de/handytarife/einsteiger-tarife/smartphone-100/page/2.html

I'm trying to use, for example, `xpath=//input[@data-name="Internet-Flat 750"]`
to identify the options, but it doesn't work.

What i have done:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>${tarifoption}</td>
    <td>tarifoption</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>${tarifoption2}</td>
    <td>tarifoption2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>${tarifoption3}</td>
    <td>tarifoption3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>if</td>
    <td>storedVars['tarifoption'&amp;&amp;'tarifoption2'&amp;&amp;'tarifoption3'].m‌​atch(/^keine$/);</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=input.btn.btn-primary</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>else</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

What i want that IF ALL 3 Options are not selected it will go next screen and that i am trying to archieve with `storedvars`

```
storedVars['tarifoption','tarifoption2',tarifoption3'].match(/^keine$/);
```

Thank you!

Comment: What i have done:    <tr>
 <td>store</td>
 <td>${tarifoption}</td>
 <td>tarifoption</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>store</td>
 <td>${tarifoption2}</td>
 <td>tarifoption2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>store</td>
 <td>${tarifoption3}</td>
 <td>tarifoption3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>if</td>
 <td>storedVars['tarifoption'&amp;&amp;'tarifoption2'&amp;&amp;'tarifoption3'].match(/^keine$/);</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>css=input.btn.btn-primary</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>else</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: What i want that IF ALL 3 Options are not selected it will go next screen and that i am trying to archieve with storedvars storedVars['tarifoption','tarifoption2',tarifoption3'].match(/^keine$/);

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
//label[@data-name="Internet-Flat 750"]
```

as the tag is `label` not `input`

Comment: Hello Madhan, i did  xpath=//label[@data-name="Internet-Flat 750"] it still not working it says as an error: [error] This element has no value; is it really a form field?

Comment: i am doing : storevalue  xpath=//label[@data-name="Internet-Flat 750"]  to make an if  with that value

Comment: What do you want to do with that click on that button?

Comment: i want to do:   IF 3 options are NOT enabled go next screen ...  if 2 options are enabled in the XML -> enable them on website and go next screen

Comment: Add these details to your question and post what have you done

Comment: i did ^^ sry for bothering you